# Webpage redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

My website had been hacked and lots of pages had been added and these have been indexed by Google. This has seriously affected the amount of traffic my site is receiving.

These pages all are all named along the lines of - '?mulberry-948.html' just with a different number for each.

I have deleted all these pages but there are back links to these from lots of websites around the web so Google is still looking for them.

Is it possible to redirect all of these pages use .htacess in a simple way without having to add a redirect for each file.

i.e can i say for anything that begins with '?mulberry' to be redirected to index.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i say for anything that begins with '?mulberry' to be redirected to index.html?

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mulberry [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

`?` in the end will strip off any existing query string.